# Is it permissible for a Jew to hire a gentile to operate a business during Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, business

This question is pretty straightforward.

Say that I own a business which is commonly open on shabbat ***(A mechanic or law firm or similar common business practice)***

Is it permissible for me to hire on a non-Jew to operate the business during Shabbat so that my non-Jewish customers would still have access to my services during their weekend?

Are there any rules or limitations around such an arrangement that someone should be aware of?

Comment: As a general rule, you're not allowed to have a non-Jew work on your behalf on shabbos. There may be [workarounds](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96075/6592) depending on the circumstances, but you would have to consult with a competent rabbi.

Comment: highly related and maybe duplicate: [Operating a business on Shabbat with a non-Jewish partner](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/108832/11501)

Comment: The answer is yes (through a partnership, not a straight employment contract) but the details are complicated, the above answer covers some of them, see sources there for further study and be sure to consult a Rabbi before setting up anything like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you, alone, own the business (not with a non-Jewish partner), I would say you may not hire a non-Jew to operate it on Shabbat.  The Ohr HaChaim writes about Exodus 20:10:

> The Torah may also wish to remind us that performance of work on Shabbat is prohibited whether performed by a Jew or by a Gentile on his behalf. The word לֹֽ֣א־תַעֲשֶׂ֣֨ה lo taaseh, “[work] shall not be done”, is in the passive form, which means that, whereas it is permissible for a Jew to have his work performed by Gentiles during the week, on Shabbat his work must not be performed at all by anybody.